# conflicting requests install php-zip on fedora

Tags: php, linux, zip, fedora, yum

I'm trying to install php-zip but I get a conflict error:

```
 Problem: conflicting requests
  - nothing provides libzip(x86-64) >= 1.8.0 needed by php-pecl-zip-1.19.5-1.fc34.remi.8.0.x86_64
  - nothing provides libzip(x86-64) >= 1.8.0 needed by php-pecl-zip-1.20.0-1.fc34.remi.8.0.x86_64
```

Answer (score 1):

This library is available in "remi" repository, which seems to not be enabled.

https://rpms.remirepo.net/fedora/34/remi/x86_64/repoview/libzip.html

Comment: `sudo dnf --enablerepo=remi install libzip` and
`sudo dnf install libzip php-zip`

Answer (score 0):

No need  pear package, just use the below command. 
*sometime need check os version then use compatible repo*

```sh
$ dnf install libzip-dev libzip php-zip php-devel -y
$ php -m | grep zip
> zip
```